# Add html code to php implode function to returned data

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, function, implode

I have this little function running at my wordpress site. But I need to add a bit of data to it. Hope I can get help.

```
Function array_to_comma($data)
{

    if (is_array($data) and count($data) > 0) 
    {
        $data = implode(', ', $data);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Which outputs this:

```
Some Data, Some Data, Some Data
```

But I want to add some html code to it, a span, but I do not know how. So that it would appear like this in the source code of a rendered page. I see that it already adds a comma, but I cannot figure out to get to add more data then just the comma to appear at start and end. like this:

```
<span special="codes">Some Data</span>, <span special="codes">Some Data</span>, <span special="codes">Some Data</span>
```

Thank you in anticipation of a great help!. I am a php noob :)

**EDIT:** I have successfully used this code below. from the answer from elclanrs.

```
function array_to_comma($data)
{
    if (is_array($data) and count($data) > 0) {
        $data = '<span special="code">'
            . implode('</span>,<span special="code">', $data)
            .'</span>';
        return $data;       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
$result = '<span>'. implode('</span>,<span>', $data) .'</span>';
```

You can do this to add attributes:

```
$span = '<span special="codes">';
$result = $span . implode('</span>,'. $span, $data) .'</span>';
```

**Edit:** It could be abstracted more to be reused:

```
function wrapInTag($arr, $tag='span', $atts='', $sep=',') {
  return "<$tag>". implode("</$tag>$sep<$tag $atts>", $arr) ."</$tag>";
}

// Printing a list
echo '<ul>'. wrapInTag(['one','two','three'], 'li', 'class="item"') .'</ul>';
```

Comment: Thanx! It worked. I edited my post to reflect. I cannot upvote (sorry) because I am a noob :( i have no rep!

Answer (score 1):

First add the string:

```
foreach ($data as $key=>$val){
    $data[$key] = '<span special="codes">'.$val.'</span>';
}
```

then perform your implode to get the commas in place.

Comment: +1 You can also use double-quotes for readability. (`"<span special='codes'>$val</span>"`)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can fix it after you implode:

```
Function array_to_comma($data)
{    
    if (is_array($data) and count($data) > 0) 
    {            
        foreach($data as $elem)
        {
            $elem = "<span special=\"codes\">" . $elem . "</span>"
        }   
        $data = implode(', ', $data); 
        return $data;    
    }
}
```

Comment: foreach won't work the way you are expecting. $data=implode returns a string

Comment: Ahh... Sorry, I'll fix it

Comment: Why so much mess with the quotes?